# Want to show detailview, clicking in a link in a listview

Tags: django

I want to show the detail from a school, which will show all the students but when i run the code, it doesnt find the url, i've been searching for the answer all over the web but still dont get it, the point is to show a list of all the schools in a list.html file, that works okay, but when i want to click in an item from that list, it supposed to show the details from that school which will be all the students attending that school, but it returns a 404 error, saying that it didnt find the url.

```
####MODELS

# Create your models here.
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Students(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='students')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

####VIEWS
from django.views.generic import View,DetailView,ListView
from .models import *

# Create your views here.
class Index(View):
    def get(self,request):
        return HttpResponse('Hello World')

class SchoolList(ListView):
    model = School
    template_name = 'firstapp/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'School'

class SchoolDetails(DetailView):
    model = School
    template_name = 'firstapp/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'School_detail'



####URLS
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('list/',views.SchoolList.as_view(),name='list'),
    path('School_detail/<int:pk>',views.SchoolDetails.as_view(),name='details')
]

####LIST HTML

{%extends 'firstapp/base.html'%}
{%block body_block%}

<h1>Here is a list of the schools!</h1>
{%for school in School%}
<p><a href="{{school.id}}">{{school.name}}</a></p>
{%endfor%}
{%endblock%}


####DETAIL HTML

{%extends 'firstapp/base.html'%}
{%block body_block%}

{%for student in school_detail.students.all%}
<p>{{student.name}}</p>
{%endfor%}

{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link is not defined right

```
<p><a href="{{school.id}}">{{school.name}}</a></p>
```

should be

```
<p><a href="{% url 'details' school.id%}>{{school.name}}</a></p>
```

Let me know if this solves the problem

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks Clementine! it solved the entire problem!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many reasons why using the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) is a good idea, because it is harder to make mistakes when you construct a URL in a template.

The URL should be `School_detail/{{school.pk}}`, but as said, it is better not to render this that way:

```
<p><a href="{% url 'details' school.id %}">{{school.name}}</a></p>
```

With this Django will look for a `path(..)` where the `name='details'`, and replace the (first) parameter with `school.pk`.

Comment: Wow man, thanks, yeah it worked, that was the problem, it solved the whole problem!